# Cannot import modules in a same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, importerror

I currently have a problem with my code, which is akin to the one below:

```
import apples.py as apple

apple.foo()
```

When I try to import `apples.py` module (self-made and in the same folder), it raises an error:

> ERROR - apples.py module not found.

What can I do? It's a rather heavy script, and putting it into a single script collapses python due to lack of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a directory:

```
mydir
|----> __init__.py
|----> apples.py
|----> example.py
```

You can use `foo()` in `apples.py` from `example.py` by:

```
import apples

apples.foo()
```

You can read more about modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: with directory you mean the folder? I'm quite new on what that term is (also, my English isn't the best on programming, which doesn't help at all). Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Yes, it is. `mydir` is the folder containing three files.

Comment: *but without the __init.py__ file. I don't know if it's relevant or not. Also, excuse the split message, I'm typing on phone and, oh, well...

Comment: It is relevant to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. So, not in your case.

Comment: Then we are in the starting point again (I'll upload a better example as soon as I get home, for I am currently on my way and I don't expect to arrive in less than an hour and a half